# Vue.js redirect to a new page/component if F5 is pressed

Tags: javascript, vue.js, onbeforeunload

New to vue.js here. 
I have deployed a complete form website with 3 components : Id, Form and End

Everything is working really well! I am only struggling with one action.

If a user hits F5 to reload the page when he is on the component /Form, the page goes blank... which is a pretty bad experience... What I have done is, I added a window.onbeforeunload action, it will display a popup asking if the user really wants to leave the page. If user answers "leave", I want the page to redirect to /Id.

Current Scenario is : 
/Id ---> /Form ---> F5 ---> pop up confirm leave page --yes--> /Form (blank page)

What I would like is :
/Id ---> /Form ---> F5 ---> pop up confirm leave page --yes--> /Id

When I run window.onbeforeunload as below, it works well :

```js
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    return "Are you sure?";
}
```

But when I try to use the combination of window.onbeforeunload and        this.$router.push('/Id'), it does not seem to work at all... or I am just doing it wrong.

Here is how I tried to add this.$router.push('/Id') :

```js
<script>
import axios from 'axios'
var answer =''

window.onbeforeunload = function(){
  var answer = confirm('Are you sure?');
  if (answer == 'true'){
    this.$router.push('/Id')
  }
  return answer;
}

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      
      form: {
        ....
      },
    }
  },
  
  methods: {
    ....
    }
   ....
   ...
 ...
```

Comment: can you show the code where you use the `this.$router.push('/Id')` ?

Comment: I updated my post with the code used with this.$router.push('/Id'). Basically I try to retrieve the answer of the pop up, if user say "yes leave" then push to /Id

Comment: Even using window.location="URL" does not work...
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
  var answer = confirm('Do you want to quit ?');
  if (answer){
    window.location="http://www.yahoo.com/"
  }
  return answer;
}
The pop up message appears - I answer "leave". But then I get a blank page....

Comment: what's the data like when the page is blank ? use that data to determine whether the page is blank, and redirect in `created` hook if it is

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found a way to do it on my desktop by using the following code :

```js
var
  is_asked = false;

window.onbeforeunload = 
  function (ev) {
    var e = ev || window.event;
    window.focus();
    if (!is_asked){
      is_asked = true;
      var showstr = "CUSTOM_MESSAGE";
      if (e) {  //for ie and firefox
        e.returnValue = showstr; 
      }
      return showstr; //for safari and chrome
    }
  };

window.onfocus =
  function (ev){
    if (is_asked){
      window.location.href = "http://localhost:8080";
    }
  }
```

But still no luck on my mobile....

when I use safari on my desktop it works well but when I use safari on mobile I get a blank page again. I think there is something related to window.onbeforeunload not supported by mobile?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by using localstorage.

Instead of redirecting to the Home page I stored the form data on the localstorage and everything is fine now - https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-localstorage